# Ubuntu Internet Connection Issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

OK so I just got onto Ubuntu and I am not sure where to turn or what to do. I have been having some issues with my WiFi connection. No problems with Windows but I need to keep connecting and reconnecting several times. I have tried searching for answers but to no avail.

Just in case you would like to know, here is my ifconfig details from the terminal:

```
sricharan@sricharan-Lenovo-B460e:~$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:d9:c0:40  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:983381 (983.3 KB)  TX bytes:983381 (983.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:d0:41:cb:6a:6f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2d0:41ff:fecb:6a6f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39808450 (39.8 MB)  TX bytes:4330242 (4.3 MB)
```

Looking forward to your support and a solution.

Comment: ok so just now, I have to disconnect and reconnect to wifi 2 times..

Comment: So... you're just having the connection drop intermittently? I'm not sure I totally understand the issue.

Have you tried using iwconfig? (Given you're using wifi)

Comment: Yup, it says that I am connected to the Wifi but after a few minutes when I click on a link or redirect to a new website (say going from here to google.com), it will just keep processing and will not take to me to google. Then I need to disconnect and reconnect... please advice..

Comment: I just checked the man log notes for iwconfig and I do not understand what it does... could you please guide me on what perhaps needs to be done...